# Как удалить в MySql различные значения от символа до символа

Tags: mysql, wordpress

К примеру есть таблица wp_posts в которой существует колонка post_content

Нужно удалить с помощью запроса из post_content любой набор символов от значения  "начало" до значения "конец"

Как это сделать?

Comment: Любой набор - `*.`. А в ВП нужно не лазить в базу руками, а использовать плагины для замены. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Comment: Благодарю, но плагины не подходят, так как они способны заменить отдельные конкретные значения. А мне нужно удалить каждый раз разные значения между конкретными символами.

Comment: Плагины как раз не позволят заменить не нужное. Хотя бы на скрины посмотрел.